# Delete Status Change CaseFeed notifications on Case record

Tags: apex, process-builder, case, configuration, process

Whenever the status of the case is changed, a chatter notification is posted on the case record. I need some automation to delete those status change posts by using mechanism. Please suggest the better approach to do it without effecting the case history.

Comment: You probably need to write or a trigger or a batch class to do that. I will suggest a batch.

Comment: A batch wouldn't prevent them from entering the case feed. A trigger would be the way to do this.

Comment: We have implemented this with the help of process builder and a flow on a condition whenever the Type of CaseFeed is ChangeStatus then delete the post. Will there be any disadvantage of using this?